# How to make a UITableViewCell expand and collapse animated using AutoLayout in iOS 7 and iOS 8?

Tags: uitableview, animation, autolayout

I want to resize the height of a UITableViewCell moving down cells below it, I don't know how to do that using Autolayout in iOS 7 or iOS 8. Can anyone help me?, please